# Fancybox wrap img number into separate span

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox gallery with a caption, containing title and image number:  e.g. `Title 1/2`

I'd like to have the image number on the right side of the image and the title on the left. Therefore I need to wrap the img Number into a separate span tag. How do I do this?

Thats the existing markup:

```
<div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-float-wrap">
   <span class="child">5 / 7 - Soitinrakentajat pajalla, 2012</span>
</div
```

but it Should be:

```
<div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-float-wrap">
   <span class="child">Soitinrakentajat pajalla, 2012</span>
   <span class="text-right">5 / 7</span>
</div>
```

The img numers are generated like this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterLoad : function() {this.title = (this.index + 1) + ' / ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');}
    });
```

How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.title = "<span class='mySpanLeft'>" + (this.title ? this.title : '') + "</span>" + "<span class='mySpanRight'>Image " + (this.index + 1) + ' / ' + this.group.length + "</span>";
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AqL9t/)**